# Controller Creation Problem in Visual Studio .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

After updating my Visual Studio Community Edition to Version 16.7.0, I am getting an error when i am trying to Add Controller in my Asp.NET Projects.

[image]

I am using these NuGet Packages:

[image]

Anyone familiar with this or any advises to resolve this ? Thank You

Comment: EnvDTE errors usually mean a botched installation. Try a clean install.

Comment: For the whole Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

Update the NuGet Packages

1. Go to Tools-> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console.
2. Type "Update-Package -reinstall" then press Enter key.